# Debian 9: USB-volumes are not displayed in PCManFM-Qt's sidebar

Tags: debian, usb, pcmanfm, lxqt, audio-volume

I run Debian 9 with `LXQt` what is completely fine. However, attached USB-volumes are not getting displayed in the `PCManFM-Qt` sidebar in category `Devices` intended for that (see screenshot).

Which package is responsible for that?

I activated all three necessary options in `Preferences` -> `Volume`, but the drives still don't appear in the sidebar. Ironically the taskbar-widget shows the drives and I can easily open them in `PCManFM-Qt` by clicking on the widget. However they are never displayed in the sidebar while the category `Devices` remains completely empty. During common workflows that is a bit uncomfortable...

---

**Screenshot of the issue:**

[image: Empty "Devices" category when USB-device is plugged in]

**Screenshot of the working taskbar widget:**

[image: Working taskbar widget that opens the displayed device in <code>PCManFM-Qt</code> correctly]

Again, clicking on the taskbar widget the device gets opened in `PCManFM-Qt` without any problems. Only displaying its existence in the sidebar does not work.

Comment: Have to tried with terminal?

Comment: @SivaPrasath: Excuse me, I don't understand what you mean. How can I try it in terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merely the package `gvfs-backends` was missing. This package is responsible for virtual filesystems in userspace.

After installation everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Getting usb devices to show up in thunar is messy but here is the process no matter your system configuration:

1. Dbus and Xdg stuff must be installed.
2. XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11 dbus-run-session openbox-session or gnome-session (you run that in tty or put in xinitrc + startx) This loads your display environment.  If you have a login or display manager, it takes care of this step.   It is insufficient to run openbox-session since Xdg and dbus are needed as well.  3 things run in that command.
   Session type can be Wayland if compositor supports Wayland.  Openbox does not.
3. Thunar, thunar-volman and udevil must be installed computer restarted.
4. Udevil daemon thus ( udevil &) must run for a few seconds then good to launch thunar, volume management should be enabled; restart thunar if you just enabled.

Zero need for Gvfs.
You can replace udevil with bloated Gvfs if you want.
Also better to thunar --daemon on startup.